# Detection Of User-Mode Hooks

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++, hook

Is there a way (programmatically) to detect the **List of User-Mode Hooks** ? I have tried reading some articles related but could not get through. Any pointers or ideas or samples would be of great help. As I have not till now started the code, so feel free to help me either in C or C++. TIA.

**EDIT::** I am trying with an approach to enumerate all the processes currently running and then again enumerating all the modules each of the process uses. What I really want to try(as explained by some experts) is to compare the enumerated list of all modules currently loaded into memory and the list of modules on the disk of each process to check for hooking. Would somebody please shed light on this? I do not know what my question is but if you got what my confusion is, please help me out here.

Comment: There are several examples out there. For instance, Jay Satiro wrote a user hook monitor which you can download. The source code can be browsed at https://github.com/jay/gethooks

Comment: @Downvoter- Reason please. I researched and then posted the question. Not everybody gets lucky with google.

Comment: This is like trying to convince yourself that you are not crazy. If somebody has tampered with your process, the can also tamper with your code that detects whether you've been tampered with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways that usermode hooks can be implemented. For example:

1. An unconditional branch instruction can be inserted inline at the start of the function.
2. Patching of Import Address Table.
3. Some mechanism can be used to throw an exception (changing page protections, `int 3`, etc.) when the function is entered and a Vectored Exception Handler then used to redirect execution.

The method of detection differs for the method of usermode hook you are detecting. As an example,

1. The classical approach for detecting the most common method of usermode hooking (`JMP` instruction at start of target functions) is to disassemble the function and check the first instruction.
2. Resolve addresses of functions expected in IAT dynamically with `GetProcAddress` and check whether the table looks as is expected.
3. Check page protections, disassemble, etc.

I am not intending to provide an exhaustive enumeration of all possible methods of hooking (and detection), but rather to explain that there is no single generic method for generating a list of usermode hooks.

Comment: How could I compare the modules of a process on disk and in memory to recognize if there are hooks or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look for few other things first.

1. Check if there are RWX memory blocks in `Process Address Space`. It is not an intense operation like comparing each function in memory with disk.
2. For checking IAT hooks, check if `Function Address` is not outside loaded modules range.